# Manifest merger failed:uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 2 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library with support libraries v26

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

In project structure I changed minSdkVersion from 14 to 2 but I got this error. What should I do?

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 2 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\Sav.android\build-cache\a2aea10c6b6f27b1c242d8ff3af373d56d229be1\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Comment: please check your `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 2` it must be greater than 14. This may be in `gradle.build` and `manifest xml`

Comment: Why it must be greater than 14? I want Android 1.1 to run my app.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this isn't POB, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817227/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller-than-version). (The only one I could find that doesn't have answers related to as specific library, but generalizes it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library \[com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817227/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-8-cannot-be-smaller-than-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) of the **support libraries**:

> Caution: Starting with Support Library release **26.0.0** (July 2017), the **minimum supported API level across most support libraries has increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14)** for most library packages

You are using the support libraries v26 and you can't use `minSdkVersion` 2 (and no reason to use it in September 2017 since `minSdkVersion` 14 covers more than **99% of the distribution**)

[image]

Here the [updated dashboard.](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)